# how to achieve comparison queries in Django Admin by input widget not just select boxes?

Tags: python, django, database, comparison

I am just a Django beginner. I want to achieve a functionality of comparison queries in Django Admin since `search_fields` and `list_filter` could not meet my requirements.

Here is an example:

I have a table Sports which has an attribute called Speed, so naturally I want to get the querysets of all the Speed are greater than 2.
First of all I could select gt, lt, gte or lte respectively, then I could set a value by input widget as a limit, at the end I could get the querysets by clicking on search button. 
However, I have learned that `list_filter` can filter the item by select a value? Is that right? That is not what I want. Are there any methods to achieve the function?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. I think you might want a custom list filter (look at the `DecadeBornListFilter` in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)).

Comment: Excuse me, do you have any idea now? Is the description still unclear?

Comment: Adding extra inputs to select `gt` or `lt` to the admin would be quite tricky, I can't think of a straight forward way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Django QuerySet [Field Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) are very handy tools for such case:

`Sports.objects.filter(speed__gt=2)` will return the elements with speed greater than 2

in **admin.py**:

```
from datetime import date

from django.contrib import admin

class SportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    use raw_id_fields to tell django don't user select-box interface for this field
    """
    raw_id_fields = ("speed",)
    list_filter = (SportListFilter,)

class SportListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Sport'

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'speed'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
            pass

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
        provided in the query string and retrievable via
        `self.value()`.
        """
            return queryset.filter(speed__gt=int(self.value()))

class SportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (SportListFilter,)
```

Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) for more detailed example

Check [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)

Comment: I got this error from your code.Exception Value:  The SimpleListFilter.lookups() method must be overridden to return a list of tuples (value, verbose value)

Comment: By the way, how could I set a value by input widget not just select-boxs. What I mean is that first of all selecting gt, gte, lt, or lte respectively, then I can set a value by input widget. Is that difficult to achieve? I have not found any idea from the official documentation. Looking forward to your reply.